# Git rebase in detached HEAD state - what to do if I want to correct file in history and replace one in latest commit

Tags: git

I got quite confused with all merging and rebasing commands and got couple of errors. Given project is just for myself. My problem is following:

My commits in master, origin/master branch (from latest, all publicly visible):

```
Commit 4 - test_data.txt commited, same file as in commit 2 
Commit 3 - revert of commit 2, code.txt bug found, state of commit 1
Commit 2 - code.txt test_data.txt changed
Commit 1 - Everything fine
```

Now, with given history I found out the bug in code.txt. I `git checkout commit 2` and I want to make a commit 5 with corrected code.txt and original test_data.txt(included in both commit 2 and commit 4).

My question:
Is there something what I did wrong in given history/log?
What should I do now? I checked out commit 2, fixed the bug and made a commit, but couldnt push in into master branch (commit 5 was from detached HEAD). Even if I merged commit 5 and commit 4 (successfully), I couldnt puch it to master. But my main question is, what should be the proper way to handle this situation?

Thank you

Comment: Which commits are publicly visible? Did you revert with `git revert`?

Comment: I am using it only myself. All commits are public as well. only decribed changes were made only locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've pushed commits to the master branch of a publicly available repository, then it's ill advised to rewrite history. You should make commit 5 fix on top of 4 and let 2-4 continue to have the bug in history.

However, to answer your question:

Checkout the branch tip and do an interactive rebase.

```
git rebase -i <commit 1>
```

Change `pick` to `edit` on commit 2. Make your changes, then continue.

```
git rebase --continue
```

Now history has been rewritten and you will need to force push the branch.

```
git push origin master --force
```

And because of these shenanigans, others will have to force update.

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```